# Why CanDeactivate Guard Can't read a method in my component?

Tags: angular, angular-router-guards

I am loading my routes lazily. I am trying to use `CanDeactivate` as per the documentation but it seems that the guard can not read the component's properties or methods.

This is my guard,

```
@Injectable()
export class CanDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<PatientRegistrationFormComponent> {
  constructor() {}
  canDeactivate(component: PatientRegistrationFormComponent) {
    return component.isChangesSaved();
  }
}
```

`isChangesSaved()` is a method inside the component.

```
public isChangesSaved(): Observable<boolean> {
    if (this.isDirtyForm()) {
      return this.confirmService.confirmUnsavedChanges();
    }
    return of(false);
  }
```

This is the error,

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'isChangesSaved' of null TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'isChangesSaved' of null at
>   CanDeactivateGuard.push../src/app/core/database/database-cores/registry-core/guards/patient-registration.guard.ts.CanDeactivateGuard.canDeactivate

Here is my module (lazy loaded)

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RegistryRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    RegistryContainerComponent,
    RegistryHomeComponent,
    PatientRegistrationFormComponent, // component of interest ….
  ],
  exports: [PatientRegistrationFormComponent],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
  providers: [
    …fromGaurds.guards,  // all my guards are loaded here….
    { provide: ErrorStateMatcher, useClass: ShowOnDirtyErrorStateMatcher },
    ToastService,
  ],
})
export class RegistryModule {}
```

and this is my routing module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: RegistryContainerComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: RegistryHomeComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'patientregistration',
        component: PatientRegistrationFormComponent,
        canDeactivate: [fromGaurds.CanDeactivateGuard],

        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            component: PatientRegistrationFormComponent,
             canActivate: [fromGaurds.PatientRegistryGuard],
            canDeactivate: [fromGaurds.CanDeactivateGuard],
          },
          {
            path: ':id',
            component: PatientRegistrationFormComponent,
            canActivate: [fromGaurds.PatientRegistryRecordGuard],
            canDeactivate: [fromGaurds.CanDeactivateGuard],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class RegistryRoutingModule {}
```

is this a bug or wrong implementation of the interface?

**Update**

I tired adding the guard to the lazy loading module. 
This is the parent module for the child module `RegistryModule` mentioned above,

```
const dbRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DbHomeComponent,
    data: { preload: true },
    canDeactivate: [fromGaurds.CanDeactivateGuard],
    children: [
      { path: '', component: UsersDashboardComponent },
      {
        path: 'registry',
        canActivate: [RoleGuardService],
        data: { expectedRole: { roles: ['reg'] } },
        loadChildren: '../database-cores/registry-core/modules/registry.module#RegistryModule',
      },
      {
        path: 'cloudstorage',
        canActivate: [RoleGuardService],
        loadChildren:
          '../database-cores/cloud-storage-core/modules/cloud-storage.module#CloudStorageModule',
      },
    ],
  },
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(dbRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class DbRoutingModule {}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DbHeaderComponent,
    DbFooterComponent,
    DbHomeComponent,
    UsersDashboardComponent,
  ],
  imports: [

    }),
  ],
  exports: [],
  providers: [
    ...fromGaurds.guards,
    MDBSpinningPreloader,
    ToastService,
    DirectoryService,
  ],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
})
export class DbModule {}
```

Comment: The lazy loaded component is null in your guard. Try the following solution(s) https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16868#issuecomment-331037915

Comment: @Jags I tried to load my guard in the parent module (where I am defining my lazy loaded children modules) and it did not work.

Comment: When you say parent module, which module do you mean? You should be loading the guard in the lazy loaded module imports via the RouterModule.forChild()

Comment: @jags, I updated my post, is this the proper way you are referring to?

Comment: According to [Victor Savkin](https://github.com/vsavkin), and I quote 
>>only routes that have components set should receive them. It's expected behavior.
Makes sense no?

Comment: Apologies I must have misread the first time around, it looks like you already were loading the guard within the lazy loaded module. Did you track down the issue? Do you have a plunkr?

Comment: no worries, but this is becoming rather confusing to me, here is a [repo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v9djs1). things just work fine there!, I even loaded the guard in the lazily loaded module.

Comment: That is strange. The only major difference I can see is how you are providing your guards with the spread operator in the question code snippet. I've had issues with the spread separator and Intellij Intellisense before, but not with the component tree so I can't imagine that would be the cause of the issue. Might be worth a try though.

Comment: I love it, we are on the same page, I just did. Lol not working. This thing is driving me crazy now

Comment: I even updated my packages, fresh npm and yet nothing is changing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178412/discussion-between-json-and-jags).

Comment: @Jags, ok sorted out. I don't know if it makes sense but if you noticed that I am using the same component for new/edit operations `PatientRegistrationFormComponent`. removing `canDeactivate` from the children tree does the trick. any idea why?

Comment: I mentioned this in the chat, but due to how your routes are set up I think your deactivate guard is firing twice. You probably don't need the child route for edit, just use a route resolver instead if you want to load data.

Comment: Thank you, would you please post it as an answer. you earned the points for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-asygcc) to reproduce the issue. The core of the issue is that the same deactivate guard for the same component is firing twice. The second time it fires, the component has already been deactivated and no longer exists, and hence the error.

The offending code is in the RegistryRoutingModule. The parent route `'patientregistration'` and child route `''` are both active at the same time, and use the same guard. If you remove one of the guards it should work. Depending on your use case you could remove the guards from the parent or child, however given the guard is going to cascade, you could remove from all the children.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: RegistryContainerComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: RegistryHomeComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'patientregistration',
        component: PatientRegistrationFormComponent,
        canDeactivate: [fromGaurds.CanDeactivateGuard],

        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            canActivate: [fromGaurds.PatientRegistryGuard]
          },
          {
            path: ':id',
            canActivate: [fromGaurds.PatientRegistryRecordGuard]
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Comment: for future reference, the below answer works as well.

Answer (score 1):

Sorted out. Credit goes to [sliceofbytes](https://github.com/sliceofbytes)

The problem also is in duplicating my component in the parent and children  paths as well

The following config also works as intended. `canDeactivate` serves both children paths. I believe the core issue was that I had only one instance of `PatientRegistrationFormComponent` that served both children routes.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sbdkxf) is a repo.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: RegistryContainerComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: RegistryHomeComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'patientregistration',
        //component: PatientRegistrationFormComponent, <---- here was the core issue
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            component: PatientRegistrationFormComponent,
             canActivate: [fromGaurds.PatientRegistryGuard],
             canDeactivate: [fromGaurds.CanDeactivateGuard],
          },
          {
            path: ':id',
            component: PatientRegistrationFormComponent,
            canActivate: [fromGaurds.PatientRegistryRecordGuard],
            canDeactivate: [fromGaurds.CanDeactivateGuard],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class RegistryRoutingModule {}
```